# How to globally PREVENT json rendering in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, respond-to

I have a rails application in which most of the actions respond to json.

Is there any "switch" I can turn off to prevent all the controllers from responding to json despite the `respond_to` method call, or I still have to disable it manually in every action (which seems very odd).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a proposal, though a bit hacky I'm afraid :)

```
class < ApplicationController
  before_filter :disable_json

  def disable_json
    if request.format =~ /json/
      //do something you like, redirect_to or reply with message
    end
  end
```

The before_filter will be fired before any specific controller's method.

The json header is usually "application/json"

For `request`, you can read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object

Comment: Actually this is a very good solution, couldn't find any better one, thanks :)

Comment: @TamerShlash, my pleasure :) Not sure why you revised the operator as exact match as the format may contain other characters except 'json'. I think REGEX match should be better and revised that.

Comment: It gave me an error because it was `~=` not `=~`, I didn't know what the problem was because I'm not familiar with Ruby Regex, thanks again :)

Comment: @TamerShlash, yes, that was a misspelling, sorry. Fixed in last edit.

Comment: In Rails 4 the `request.format` is of type `Mime::Type` which doesn't interpret the `=~` operator correctly. Use `if request.format.to_s =~ /json/` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it in routes.rb, using constraints:

```
# Only allow HTML requests for all resources within the block
scope constraints: {format: :html} do
  resources :posts
  resources :comments
  get "/profile", to: "users#profile"
end
```